# Variable value stays through multiple test cases

Tags: c++, arrays

My code takes in an array of positive and negative numbers. It then spits out what percentage of the array is Positive, negative, and zero. When my code runs through multiple test cases, some of the variables that I have initialized stay the same? Which is something i've never encountered before and I wonder if I am initiaizing them correctly. Here is my Code and a couple of test cases

```
void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
int pos = 0; 
int neg = 0;
int zer = 0;

cout << len <<"\n";

double d = len; 
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sum3 = 0;

for(int i =0; i<len; i++){
   if(arr[i]>=1) {
       pos++;
   } 
   if(arr[i]<0) {
       neg++;
   } 
   if(arr[i]==0) {
       zer++; 
   } 
}  
    sum1 = pos/d;
    cout << sum1 <<"\n";
    sum2 = neg/d;
    cout << sum2<<"\n";
    sum3 = zer/d;
    cout << sum3<<"\n";
}
```

an example of a test case that works is

```
6
-4 3 -9 0 4 1
```

an example of one that does not is

```
8
1 2 3 -1 -2 -3 0 0
```

Comment: cout << len <<"\n" == 6 in first test case and 6 in the second which makes no sense to me since len is reinitialized every time the program is run.

Comment: You can always [edit] your post to add additional information as you like, or on others request.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is wrong when working with `std::vector`.  It will give you the stack size of the vector in bytes - likely the size of a pointer plus a length, plus whatever other metadata is stored in the class.  You want `arr.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

This is typically used in normal arrays. Since you are using a vector, try instead to use:

```
int len = arr.size();
```

Why? `sizeof` [yields the size in bytes of the object representation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) of the argument. For vectors, that's always `24` no matter how many elements. And `sizeof` for an element of that `vector<int>`, is just `sizeof(int)`, which is usually `4` bytes. Badabing badaboom, `sizeof(vector<int>)/sizeof(vector<int>[0])` is always 6.